# Objects in an Array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, object

How do I create multiple instances of an identical object and call them in an array in an efficient manner?
I am aware of for-loops, but am not familiar with Objective-C syntax. This is what I currently have:

ViewController.h

```
NSArray *wArray;
NSInteger w0, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7 , w8, w9, w10, w11, w12, w13, w14, w15, w16, w17, w18, w19, w20, w21, w22, w23, w24, w25, w26, w27, w28;

@property NSArray *wArray;
@property NSInteger w0, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8, w9, w10, w11, w12, w13, w14, w15, w16, w17, w18, w19, w20, w21, w22, w23, w24, w25, w26, w27, w28;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@synthesize w0, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7 , w8, w9, w10, w11, w12, w13, w14, w15, w16, w17, w18, w19, w20, w21, w22, w23, w24, w25, w26, w27, w28, wArray;

wArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: w0, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7 , w8, w9, w10, w11, w12, w13, w14, w15, w16, w17, w18, w19, w20, w21, w22, w23, w24, w25, w26, w27, w28, nil];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `NSInteger` is a typedef of an integer (exact size depends on your target), it's not an object. `NSArray` only takes objects.

Comment: You don't put pointers/properties in an array, you put objects there.  Unless you initialize w0..w28 with pointers to objects nothing will go into the array.  (And, as DrummerB states, you can't put an NSInteger in an array either -- use an NSNumber, which is an object.)

Comment: @DrummerB `NSInteger` is a `typedef` of `int`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Right, I should get some sleep..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a NSMutableArray and use:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        [array addObject:someObject];
    }
```

And if you want to store integers you can use:

```
NSNumber *someObject = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1];
```

You can then access these objects by:

```
[array objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: will my objects be numbered (w0,w1,w2,etc.)?

Comment: Look in my answer how you can access these.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use array of `int` as

```
int num[29]; //NSInteger and int are the same
```

And access them as

```
num[0] = 15;
num[1] = 19;
...
...
...
```

Comment: how about if I were to store UIImageViews?

Comment: For that you can use `NSMutableArray` to store `UIImageView` objects

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
    [yourarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"w%d",i]];
 }
```